# require 'dalli' returns false in the console, although it is in the gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, dalli, memcachier

Following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier#ruby

I added memcachier and dalli gems, and did a bundle install

then I ran the console

and I typed

```
require 'dalli'
```

and it returns false

and I can't tell why, it also does this in a staging and production environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test those in irb

Try:

```
gem install dalli
gem install memcachier
```

And after that require them:

```
require 'dalli'
require 'memcachier'
```

If you want to test in your app console, you don't need to require them just do that:

```
cache = Dalli::Client.new
cache.set("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: How do I do that in a heroku environment? and why isn't it installing from my gemfile?

Comment: @bezzoon Try `heroku run bash` and do stuff?

Comment: @manu29.d I am actually doing that right now! and it says localhost:11211 failed (count: 1) Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - send